# bulleted list in cv markdown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, cv, markdown-rendering

Is it me or does the markdown in the cv editor not support a bulleted list?

I tried to add one in the responsibilities section for a previous employer and it doesn't render with bullets. The edit box has the 'this field supports rich markdown formatting. live preview' text below it so I thought the '  - ' would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't repro this.

I entered the following text for responsibilities:

```
- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3
```

And I got this on the public cv view:

http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/1281/image3i.png

Comment: I was missing the empty line between the previous line and the bulleted list and I had a couple of spaces after that previous line so it appeared to kind of work. Should have played with it a little more...